# How to enable real time object access analytics in google cloud storage?

Tags: google-analytics, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to set up real time access logs for objects stored in a google cloud storage bucket. The access logs that google specifies [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs) are generated every hour and won't work.

I would like similar information about object access(ip, amount downloaded, client_os) but in real time. Is there a way to do this on the google cloud platform?

If it would be better to route the traffic through another point with real time logs I would appreciate advice on how one would do that and with what tools. Ultimately, I want to have the data visualized in google data studio.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately,  google storage only provide following [gcp-storage metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-storage)

```
- api/request_count
- authz/acl_based_object_access_count
- authz/object_specific_acl_mutation_count
- network/received_bytes_count
- network/sent_bytes_count
- storage/object_count
- storage/total_byte_seconds
- storage/total_bytes
```

I think you want access log for your bucket objects, such as images, videos...etc.
You maybe you can try to use [Google Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/logging?authuser=1&hl=en) in front of your bucket .
So you can get access log you need by **[httpRequest](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry?authuser=1#HttpRequest)**, and get from stackdriver

```
{
  "requestMethod": string,
  "requestUrl": string,
  "requestSize": string,
  "status": number,
  "responseSize": string,
  "userAgent": string,
  "remoteIp": string,
  "serverIp": string,
  "referer": string,
  "latency": string,
  "cacheLookup": boolean,
  "cacheHit": boolean,
  "cacheValidatedWithOriginServer": boolean,
  "cacheFillBytes": string,
  "protocol": string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of the Logs for Cloud Storage:

1. [Access logs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs) - updated on hourly rate logging all the requests for the specified bucket.
2. Storage logs - updated daily, providing all the information about storage usage from the last day.
3. **[Audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/audit-logs)** - **tracks access on the continuous basis**, this is [recommended](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#should-you-use) way to log your storage activity for autenticated users.

You can see Audit logs in the Google Cloud Platform Console > Activity [Activity Stream](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity).

> Resource type filter: `GCS bucket`.

A more detailed version of the logs can be found in the [Logs Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview).

If you need to use logs for further analytics, [there are several options to do so](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/exporting-stackdriver-logging-for-security-and-access-analytics) provided in the Google Cloud documentation. There is also example query to visualize data in Data Studio. [Check more custom queries for Data Studio here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/exporting-stackdriver-logging-for-security-and-access-analytics).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I looked into audit logs and while they are generated real time, Google has chosen to disable them for public cloud storage objects. Any idea about how to get around the public access restriction on audit logs?

Comment: Audit logs are conservatively restricted to authenticated users only (this excludes allUsers access) to prevent unauthorized logging of user private data, like email or device ID, IP. All authenticated users access is logged, [including one granted using tokens](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#apiauth)